# $X_1,X_2,...$ real independent random variables $\not\implies S_n = \frac{1}{n}(X_1+ \cdots + X_n)$ are independent

Tags: random-variables, stochastic-calculus

Is it possible to show the following **Lemma**:

Given independent real random variables $(X_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$,

then $(S_n := \frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots + X_n))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent as well.

---

If so, any hints?

Using this lemma I would be able to solve my homework. But so far I didn't manage to proof mentioned lemma -- is it possible at all?

---

So as this is not possible, I can't use Kolmogoroff ($S_n$ are not independent) to show the following:

$X_1,...$ independent, $S_n := \frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots + X_n)$ and $A := \{x: \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) \text{ exists in } \mathrm{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}\}$
Then: $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$.

See here: [Why is the probability that $(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/n$ converges either $0$ or $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410365/x-1-indepentend-real-random-variables-s-n-and-the-tail-sigma-algebra)

Comment: Consider a much simpler case first, with $X_1$ and $X_2$ being Bernoulli i.i.d. Are $X_1$ and $X_1+X_2$ independent?

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly false. When trying to find counter-examples, you often just have to think simple. For example, let $X_1=X$ be some random variable, and let $X_2=x$ be some constant $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent but $S_1=X$ and $S_2=\frac{1}{2}X+\frac{1}{2}x$ which clearly aren't independent.

Comment: Can you help me out with some "intuition", why this is *clearly* the case? Sadly I've got no intuition about independence of random variables yet..

Comment: @mathematikler: Well, $S_1$ is just the first variable in the sequence, $S_2$ is the average of the first two variables, $S_3$ the average of the first three variables etc. Now, if the average of the first two, $S_2$, is large, then we might suspect that the average of the first three, $S_3$, is large as well. In general, knowing the value of $S_{n-1}$ of course has an impact on what we believe $S_n$ might be and hence they are not independent.

Answer (score 0):

Your lemma is false. Consider $S_1 = X_1$ and $S_2 = \frac{X_1+X_2}{2}$. Intuitively, it must be the case that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are dependent as knowledge of the value of $S_1$ gives us some information about the value of $S_2$.

Comment: Ok, I see the point.. So I need to solve the homework task somehow different, since I can't use Kolmogoroff then. I'll add the parts in the question

Comment: You should post a separate question. Changing the question will invalidate the answers that have been given already.