# Why is the probability that $(X_1+\ldots+X_n)/n$ converges either $0$ or $1$?

Tags: probability-theory

$X_1,...$ independent, $S_n := \frac{1}{n}(X_1+\cdots + X_n)$ and $A := \{x: \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n(x) \text{ exists in } \mathrm{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}\}$

Then: $P(A) \in \{0,1\}$.

---

Idea is to use Kolmogorov 0-1 law and therefore show, that $A$ is in the tail-Algebra of the $X_n$ (they're independent).

Comment: Prove that $A$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra, and use Kolmogorov $0-1$ law. Hint: for a _fixed_ $p$, $\frac{X_1+\dots+X_p}n$ goes to $0$ as $n$ to $\infty$. Hence this part does not affect the convergence of the sequence $\{S_n\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Davide Giraudo's comment makes it. Just write for arbitrary $k$
$$S_n=\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{n}=\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_k}{n} +\frac{X_{k+1}+\ldots+X_n}{n}=A_n+S_n^{(k)}$$ and observe that since $A_n$ goes to $0$, limit of $S_n$ exists iff limit of $S_n^{(k)}$ exists. The reasoning is valid for each $k$, hence
$$\{\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n \text{ exists}\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty \{\lim_{n\to \infty} S_n^{(k)}\text{ exists}\} \in \bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma(X_k,X_{k+1},\ldots),$$
which is the tail $\sigma$-algebra.